# How can I pass vector source (mbtile) from mapbox gl js or react-map-gl to deck.gl?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl, mbtiles, deck.gl, react-map-gl

As far as I understand the deck.gl documentation deck.gl layer's data must consist of:

> Array or Iterable, optional Default: []

https://uber.github.io/deck.gl/#/documentation/layer-catalog/layer?section=static-members

But I would like to get data from vector source such as mbtiles geo server and pass it down to deck gl data. I could not find any solutions to this problem. Any ideas?

What I have done so far is: successfully hosted mbtile geoserver and rendering into react-map-gl. But I could not manage to connect that mbtile data into deck gl data.

I have one idea in mind but it seems like something like that should be done already. Just query geo server with current viewport and ask for that iterable data not in mbtile fashion but simple json. By this way I may update deck gl overlay data state, which would update layer.

Comment: If you have tried anything at all then please post your effort into your question.

Comment: Looking also for something like this. Here is an example with google vector tiles, maybe this helps: https://github.com/rpk/google-maps-basemap-deckgl